# Equivalent of apt-get install python3.6-dev for conda

Tags: python, conda

How can I create a conda environment with the development version of python? Or does it already include all the necessary extension when I create one.

`conda create -n py36 python=3.6`

Answer (score 4):

`conda search python` has a maximum version of 3.6.5, so I think only stable releases are available through conda.

**edit:** some dev versions are available on conda-forge:

`conda search python --channel conda-forge` to see them

`conda create --name dev python=[version here] --channel conda-forge` to install

Comment: how do you install python-devel in an existing conda environment?