# How can I check if pip can find python dev headers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install Mujoco on a Ubuntu server and have a problem which very much looks like this: https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py/issues/265

The solution in that issue thread is to install the devel version of python3. Apparently that brings in python.h which is needed by Mujoco.

But things are complicated: I don't have root access on the machine. Pip comes from a conda environment and even on conda-forge, I don't see any dev version of python ([Equivalent of apt-get install python3.6-dev for conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50067231/equivalent-of-apt-get-install-python3-6-dev-for-conda))

The installation guide for the server installs some packages with [linuxbrew](http://linuxbrew.sh/). There is a python package on brew and apparently it automatically ships with the python devel version: [how to install python-devel in Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578106/how-to-install-python-devel-in-mac-os)

Now I have anaconda python and brew python. How can I see which paths are picked up by pip and verify if it sees the python dev headers ?